# Scheme split operation not working

Tags: list, sorting, split, scheme

I'm new to scheme and am having some trouble debugging my code.

```
; returns number of elements in a list
(define (length L)
  (cond ((null? L) 0)
        (else (+ (length (cdr L)) 1))))

; split the list in half:
; returns ((first half)(second half))
(define (split L)
  (cond 
    ((= (length L) 0) (list L L) )
    ((= (length L) 1) (list L '() ))
    (else 
      (list (sublist L 1 (/ (length L) 2) 1)
            (sublist L (+ (/ (length L) 2) 1) (length L) 1)))))

; extract elements start to end into a list
(define (sublist L start end counter)
  (cond ((null? L) L)
        ((< counter start) (sublist (cdr L) start end (+ counter 1)))
        ((> counter end) '())
        (else (cons (car L) (sublist (cdr L) start end (+ counter 1))))))
```

To me, this feels like it would split a single list into two sub lists.  There may be an easier way to do this, and so I apologize if this seems cumbersome.

Anyway, the results:

```
Expected: (split '(1 2 3 4 5)) = ('(1 2) '(3 4 5))
Actual:  (split '(1 2 3 4 5)) = ('(1 2) '(4 5))
```

It's clear that the `length` or `split` is losing the middle value, but I've checked it again and again and it seems to lose the middle value.  It seems like an easy solution would be to get rid of the `(+ 1)` of `(+ (/ (length L) 2) 1)` but this seems counter intuitive to me, as:

```
Assume L = '(1 2 3 4 5), (/ (length L) 2) = 2, and (+ (/ (length L) 2) 1) = 3
(sublist L 1 (2) 1) = '(1 2)
(sublist L (3) 5 1) = '(3 4 5)
** I put parens around the 2 and 3 to indicate that they were length calculations.
```

Clearly an assumption I am making is false, or I am overlooking something trivial.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you know the tortoise-and-hare algorithm? The tortoise walks the list, the hare runs the list at double speed. The split occurs at the position of the tortoise when the hare reaches the end of the list. Here's most of the code; I'll let you figure out the rest:

```
(define (split xs)
  (let loop ((ts xs) (hs xs) (zs (list)))
    (if (or (null? hs) (null? (cdr hs)))
        (values (reverse zs) ts)
        (loop ...))))
```

Here ts is the remaining list of items to be examined by the tortoise, hs is the remaining list of items to be examined by the hare, and zs is the list of items already examined by the tortoise, in reverse order.

Note that you never need to count the items in the input list.

Comment: That is such a cool name for an algorithm I had a hard time coming to terms with the fact you were serious ;)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not going to debug your code for you. Instead, here's a simpler definition of `split`:

```
(define (split l)
  (let ((n (length l)))
    (list (take (/ n 2) l)
          (drop (+ (/ n 2) (mod n 2)) l))))
```

Exercise for the reader: implement `take` and `drop`. The latter is just recursion on `n` while taking the `cdr` of `l` in the recursive case; the former takes slightly more effort to get right in the base case (stopping condition).

Answer (score 0):

Here is almost your solution (Racket Scheme):

```
#lang racket

(define (length lst)
  (cond [(empty? lst) 0]
        [else (+ (length (rest lst)) 1)]))

(define (first-length lst)
  (quotient (length lst) 2))

(define (second-length lst)
  (- (length lst) (first-length lst)))

(define (sublist lst start end counter)
  (cond [(empty? lst) lst]
        [(< counter start) (sublist (rest lst) start end (+ counter 1))]
        [(> counter end) '()]
        [else (cons (first lst) (sublist (rest lst) start end (+ counter 1)))]))

(define (first-half-of-list lst)
  (sublist lst 1 (first-length lst) 1))

(define (second-half-of-list lst)
  (sublist lst (second-length lst) (length lst) 1))

(define (split lst)
  (cond
    [(= (length lst) 0) (list lst lst)]
    [(= (length lst) 1) (list lst '())]
    [else (list (first-half-of-list lst) 
                (second-half-of-list lst))]))

(split '(1 2 3 4 5))

=> '((1 2) (3 4 5))
```

Thank you for good brain exercise.
The key moment is 'second-length'-function.